# Can I iterate over every instance variable of a controller with rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I loop over every instance variable "@anything" in a controller? I dont want to loop over one, I want to loop over them as a collection. Ideally scoped to the ones my controller method defines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `instance_variables` and `instance_variable_get`, e.g. like so:

```
@foo = 'Foo'
@bar = 'Bar'

instance_variables # => [:@foo, :@bar]

instance_variables.map(&method(:instance_variable_get))
# => ['Foo, 'Bar']
```

> Ideally scoped to the ones my controller method defines.

Instance variables are scoped to instances, not methods. That's why they are called instance variables. And they aren't defined by methods, in fact, they aren't defined *at all*: they just spring into existence the first time they are assigned.

Comment: instance_variables is what i was looking for, i knew about instance_variable_get, yeah i figured a method scope was asking alot. this is perfect thanks.